# How to Automatically paste data as values in another sheet in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Auto Update data which gets updated on Daily Basis based on Date , but it has one issue
basically when say Data get updated for 2nd August , Data of 1st August gets cleared as I have  written formula based on date conditions, in other words we can have only values only in one column based on the date, so I want the data of the current and previous days to be pasted as values in another sheet so that I can track and do data manipulation when it comes to Month end .

[image: Data Section]

Comment: Do you prefer Google Apps Script to formula?

Comment: yes pls if you can help me with that.

Comment: Please first check with this formula to see if it is the output you want `={{DAY(TODAY())-1,DAY(TODAY())};
OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,DAY(TODAY())+1,4,TRUE,"Data")),0,-1,3,2)}`

Comment: Hi there @Trigg! I strongly suggest you test the approach described by @idfurw. If that doesn't help, please share an example Sheet that contains the precise formulas of your scenario so we all can test it better.